# Is there any way to obtain the values of Objects from Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the structure of my data:
[image: Imgur]

I am trying to get the values of allergyId1 and allergyId2. Is there any way to obtain the values of "allergen" and "description" separately? I would like to assign those values to another class that is called Allergy and add them to an ArrayList. For example:

```
Allergy allergy = new Allergy();
ArrayList<Allergy> allergies = new ArrayList<>();

// Data of "allergyId1"
allergy.setAllergen(the value of allergen);
allergy.setDescription(the value of description);

allergies.add(allergy);
```

I've tried to convert the object that is returned to a Json object, but I think that there has to be a more efficient way to obtain the data from Firestore.

```
private void retrieveAllergiesData() {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        DocumentReference ref = db.collection(user.getUid()).document("allergies");

        ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Map<String, Object> tmp = new HashMap<>();
                        tmp = document.getData();

                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : tmp.entrySet()) {
                            Log.d("allergy", entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("fb", "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("fb", "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

This is what I get
[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works.  It doesn't get any more efficient in terms of performance than dealing with the Map that comes back for the document.

Though, you are unnecessarily creating a new Map without using it:

```
Map<String, Object> tmp = new HashMap<>();
tmp = document.getData();
```

It could be simplified like this:

```
Map<String, Object> tmp = document.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class `Allergy` with constructor and `get` `set`

```
private class Allergy  {

        private String allergen;
        private String description;

        public Allergies() {

        }

        public Allergies(String allergen, String description) {
            this.allergen = allergen;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getAllergen() {
            return allergen;
        }

        public void setAllergen(String allergen) {
            this.allergen = allergen;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
```

Then replace `Object` with `Allergy`. This probably should work in your case.

```
private void retrieveAllergiesData() {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        DocumentReference ref = db.collection(user.getUid()).document("allergies");

        ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Map<String, Allergy> tmp = new HashMap<>();
                        tmp = document.getData();

                        for (Map.Entry<String, Allergy> entry : tmp.entrySet()) {
                            String allergen = entry.getValue().getAllergen();
                            String description = entry.getValue().getDescription();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("fb", "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("fb", "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```